# Login error using Unattached Content Database Data Recovery

Tags: 2016, content-database

Within the CA of my farm I am trying to connect to retrieve a missing folder and contents using the farm admin account on UnattachedDbSelect.aspx page. After putting in my correct SQL server and instance I keep getting "Cannot open database "WSS_Content_Dept1" requested by the login. The login failed."

I can connect to the database via SMSS and telnet to the SQL server as well.  I cannot however see the server via test.udl file.  I know my servers are not using the default ports so might this be the problem?

In my error log I see:

```
w3wp.exe (0x1EA8)   0x1B3C  SharePoint Foundation   Database    880j    High    SqlError: 'Cannot open database "WSS_Content_Dept1" requested by the login. The login failed.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 4060 State: 1 Class: 11 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 65536
```

and

```
w3wp.exe (0x1EA8)   0x1B3C  SharePoint Foundation   Database    880j    High    SqlError: 'Login failed for user 'Domain\User Name'.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 18456 State: 1 Class: 14 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 65536
```

My SQL version on my production farm is 13.0.6300.2 and on the unattached database it is 13.0.6435.1.
Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164306/fixed-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed
And: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/

Comment: I found the error, script was missing a letter on the database name.